# How to set default style for arrow tips in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-styles

I am creating multiple TikZ pictures within one document and would like to set the default style of arrow heads for all the pictures to the `latex` style, i.e. like `-latex` does, so that I don't have to do this every time I draw an arrow.

I'm new to TikZ, but have searched and must not be choosing the correct terms.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use `>=latex` to specify the `latex` arrow tip, and `\tikzset` to set it globally. This will be overridden by any local definitions of the arrow tip.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[<->]
\draw [>=stealth,red] (0,.6) -- +(1,0);
\draw [blue] (0,.3) -- +(1,0);
\draw (0,0) -- +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An addendum to this excellent answer: if you’re using `tikz-cd`, then you also need to add `\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz}` for these defaults to be applied in its diagrams.