# edge direction changed by adding '-latex' option

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following is one example to illustrate my point. The two edges differs in the '-latex' option. How come this option will affect the direction. As I understand it, this option just change how the arrow tips are rendered. The result is this:
[image]

Is it a bug or a feature?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6, transform shape]
\tikzstyle{every node} = [circle, fill=gray!30]
    \node (a) at (0, 0) {A};
    \node (b) at +(0: 1.5) {B}
        edge [<-, green,dashed, -latex, bend left=30] (a)
        edge [<-, green,dashed, bend right=30] (a)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Edit:
My intention is just to change the arrrow tip style, which is achieved in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54796/how-to-set-default-style-for-arrow-tips-in-tikz). The accepted answer explains how it works.

This is the final code, which only changes the style of arrow tips, using `>=latex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6, transform shape]
\tikzset{>=latex}
\tikzset{every node/.style={circle, fill=gray!30}}
    \node (a) at (0, 0) {A};
    \node (b) at +(0: 1.5) {B}
        edge [<-, red,dashed, bend left=30] (a)
        edge [<-, red,dashed, bend right=30] (a)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a feature: use `edge [<-, green,dashed, latex-, bend left=30] (a)...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a feature; the string `latex` in `-latex` has the same syntactic behaviour as the `>` in `->`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6, transform shape]
\tikzset{every node/.style={circle, fill=gray!30}}
    \node (a) at (0, 0) {A};
    \node (b) at +(0: 1.5) {B}
        edge [latex-, red,dashed, bend left=30] (a)
        edge [<-, red,dashed, bend right=30] (a)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to expand a little: the syntax `-arrowtip` puts `arrowtip` at the end of the path; `arrowtip-` puts `arrowtip` at the beginning of the path, and `arrowtip1-arrowtip2` puts `arrowtip1` at the beginning of the path and `arrowtip2` at the end of the path.

If you want to change only the arrow tip without affecting its placement, you can use the `>=arrowtip` syntax. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6, transform shape,line width=3pt]
\tikzset{every node/.style={circle, fill=gray!30}}
    \node (a) at (0, 0) {A};
    \node (b) at +(0:1.5) {B}
        edge [->, blue,dashed, bend right=45] (a)
        edge [<-, red,dashed, bend right=30] (a)
        edge [latex->, orange,dashed, bend right=15] (a)
        edge [<-, >=latex, magenta,dashed, bend left=15] (a)
        edge [<-, blue,dashed, bend left=30] (a)
        edge [latex-, red,dashed, bend left=45] (a)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not related to the question, but I also changed the old `\tikzstyle` to `\tikzset`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We should remove `<-`, since the two are the same, resulting into `edge [latex-, red,dashed, bend left=30] (a)`

Comment: @AlbertNetymk Yes. I've edited my code accordingly.