# Problem Causal Chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikz-arrows, tikz-chains

I have been trying to make a causal chain, but I have two problems: 1) arrow should be a standard arrow without any curve "->". 2) There is a gap between the arrow and the boxes.

My code look like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{
->=LaTeX,
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=11em, 
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, ->},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=12em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=10em, 
    minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  ,every arrow/.append style={-LaTeX, >=LaTeX},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=.8cm,
  start chain=going below,]

\begin{scope}[start branch=venstre,
        %We need to redefine the join-style to have the -> turn out right
        every join/.style={->, thick, shorten <=1pt}, ]
        \node[punktchain, join=by]
            (risiko) {Expectations};
        \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
            (risiko) {Disconfirmation};
        \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
            (risiko) {Satisfaction};
        \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
            (risiko) {Repurchase Intention};
      \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And my figure like this:
[image]

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you!

Comment: Please make your code minimal and compilable! E.g. leave away proprietary fonts. "standard arrow" is very vague. Maybe you point to some head found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461 or you fix it by your self with help of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54796

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shorten <=1pt` tells TikZ you want a gap. If you don't want one, don't say that you do ;).

As mentioned in the comments 'standard arrow' is vague. Really, if you want a standard arrow you just say `->` rather than `-LaTeX` or whatever.

You might want something from the `arrows.meta` TikZ library. Try `-Stealth[]`, for example, after adding `arrows.meta` to the libraries you are loading. There are many arrow tips to choose from here. See the TikZ manual for the full list of choices.