# Tikz default arrow style and babel

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

I was trying to follow the instructions on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54797/25304), but I cannot make it work, because `babel`. My MWE:

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[main=spanish,english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

% Globally, I need it to work:
% \tikzset{>=latex}    
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Locally it works
    \tikzset{>=latex}
    \draw [->] (-2,0) -- (-2.5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So, the problem is I need babel, and I need to be able to configure the arrow heads just once, since I need to draw a lot of figures with that head, is there a way I could use this configuration outside the `tikzpicture`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For global settings of `tikzpicture` options, put them into document preamble.

Comment: I never quite understood where tikzset was supposed to go, and the manual is not very informative, I'll see how it goes, thanks!

Comment: I tried and it works, thanks! Since that solves my problem, I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I follow the instructions by [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18189/zarko) and put the `\tikzset` instruction in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[main=spanish,english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
% here
\tikzset{>=latex}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [->] (-2,0) -- (-2.5,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This way, there is no conflict with `babel` and now it works perfectly.

Comment: It is generally more appropriate to ask the person who helped you to write an answer which you can accept rather than claiming credit for it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen it before this way elsewhere, I thought it was common. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: No problem. TeX SE is a bit idiosyncratic, as I understand it. (I don't spend much time on other SE sites, but that's how it seems from discussions on Meta.) So I think on other SE sites (at least many), there'd be no social expectation of the kind I described. I think we're a bit weird ;).