# Change tikz arrowheads for whole document

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

What is the best way to set tikz arrowheads globally to one style, so that one can use `>` and `<` throughout the document (e.g. as `\path[<-]`) instead of writing `\path[latex-]` everywhere?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%something here to make both lines in the output look the same

\begin{document}

\tikz \path[->] (0,0) edge (2em,0);
\tikz \path[<-] (0,0) edge (2em,0);

\tikz \path[-latex] (0,0) edge (2em,0);
\tikz \path[latex-] (0,0) edge (2em,0);

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54796/how-to-set-default-style-for-arrow-tips-in-tikz/54797#54797

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I did use Google and the site search, but wasn't able to find this. Thank you!