# Reassigning / Declaring a new arrow type without drawing it (TikZ/PGF)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I need to draw a lot of arrows with both the `->` and `-Latex` option. I need a shorthand (preferably one character) for the `-Latex` option. If I use `\tikzset{>={Latex}}` it redefines all arrowhead which I do not want. I tried using something like `\tikzset{]={Latex}}` but it gave me the error

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/]', to which you passed 'Latex', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \tikzset{]={Latex}}

Obviously using something like `\tikzset{b>={Latex}}` also does not work.

One option is to use `\pgfarrowsdeclare` and draw the arrow from scratch. Firstly, I am not sure I can do it and secondly, it is an overkill.

Is there a way out? Can I use a very short command like `-X` to achieve `-Latex` effect but without changing all the arrows?

Comment: Maybe this example could help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54797/101651. Otherwise, you can define two styles and use one or the other when needed.

Comment: Actually the same diagram uses several `->` as well as `-Latex` arrows. Can I still try switching styles?

Comment: You didn't provide the actual code that yields the error, so it is  difficult to suggest any solution. Also, you are looking for `>=latex` *not* `-Latex`.

Comment: There is no complicated code here. Just `\tikzset{]={Latex}}` in the preamble and `\draw[dashed,-]] (A) -- (D);` between the tikzpicture environment, of course after defining A and D. I was actually looking for `-Latex` so that it can be scaled.  but even scalable `-latex will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using (or can use) the latest version of `PGF` then the `.tip` handler is pretty useful:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[X/.tip={latex}]
  \draw [->, red]   (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw [-X, green] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution worked perfect. I guess `X/.style` and `-latex` is the old version of PGF. I used this command based on your suggestion:

`\tikzset{ -X/.tip={Latex[length=3mm]} }` in the preamble and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 3):

This will work just fine.

```
\documentclass[border={10}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    -X/.style={->,>=latex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-X] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw  (0,1) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I scale `latex` arrows? something like `\tikzset{ -X/.style={->,>=latex,length=3mm} }`

Comment: EDIT: after trying the solution by @Mark I found a workaround.