# How to define tikz style in the preamble to use in all tikz pictures?

Tags: tikz-styles

How can I define a

```
stylename/.style={...}
```

in the preamble so that all `tikzpicture` environments could reference it instead of defining this style inside of each `tikzpicture`?

Comment: It seems very stange that nobody asked it before, but I can't find a duplicate :). By the way, thank you for accepting my answer!

Comment: @CarLaTeX  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42800/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54796/ are similar. (Duplicates, if any of these can be counted as such, are often difficult to find though.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right. It is very similar to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42800/101651 but not a perfect duplicate, and your other link is specific for arrows tip, whereas this one is generic. I'd leave it open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
    stylename/.style={...},
    anotherstlye/.style={...},% and so on
}
```

in your preamble, and you'll be able to use `stylename` and `anothetstyle` in all the `tikzpicture`s of your document.