# How to start with this difficult chart

Tags: diagrams, flow-charts

I need a bit of help to make a flowchart like this:

[image]

I have searched some templates to start but nothing very similar.

I don't want you to make the whole chart but some help to start. Would it be possible?

Comment: This diagram is simple enough to be handled only by means of the node-path notion of `tikz`. The broken arrows can also be drawn by either auxiliary coordinates or `decorations.pathmorphing` library: Take a look at the tones of exmples here:http://texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a part of it as a base:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[rect/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=#1,align=left} ,empty/.style={inner sep =0pt,outer sep=0pt},
myell/.style={ellipse,fill=#1,minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, draw}]
\node[rect=blue!38] (A) {Human exposure etc\\ New line\\and another line} ;
\coordinate[below=0.7 cm of A] (A1);
\coordinate[right=1 cm of A1] (A2);
\draw[-] (A1)--(A2);
\node[rect=white,below=0.2 cm of A2] (A3){text here};
\draw[->] (A2)--(A3);
\node[rect=purple!70!blue!38,below=2cm of A ] (B) {Another text \\ with two rows};
\draw[->] (A)--(B);
\node[rect=purple!70!blue!38,right=1.7cm of B] (C) {Some other text};
\node[rect=purple!70!blue!38,left=1.7cm of B] (D) {Some other text};
\coordinate[below=1cm of B] (E);
\draw[-] (B)--(E);
\coordinate[right=2.8cm of E] (F);
\draw[-] (E)--(F);
\coordinate[left=2.8cm of E] (G);
\draw[-] (E)--(G);
\node[rect=green!38,below =0.4cm of G] (H){Some texr for\\Green rectangle};
\draw[->] (G)--(H);
\node[rect=blue!38,below =0.4cm of F] (I){Some texr for\\blue rectangle};
\draw[->] (F)--(I);
\draw[->] (H)--(I) node[midway](J){};
\node[above] at (J) {\small Text over arrow};
\node[myell=blue!20,below=2cm of E] (K) {test in ellipse};
\path (H)--(K) coordinate[midway](L){};
\path[every edge,->] (H)edge[bend right=30](L);
\path (K)edge[bend left=-30](L);
\path (I)--(K) coordinate[midway](M){};
\path[every edge,->] (I)edge[bend left=30](M);
\path (K)edge[bend right=-30](M);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi koley, great, I will start with next part now. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome... Just try to understand these basic commands I used.

Comment: Any way to get it centered? I tried with `center` environment but doesn't works

Comment: @Schopenhauer did you placed the tikzpicture inside `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`? And if yes... do you have errors about overfull hbox?

Comment: yes to both of the questions..

Comment: Ok... seems that your image is too large for the textwidth. If you want to scale it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture

Comment: cool, I will try it when finished. Thanks again.

Comment: welcome... try it to see how it works because may be you have to reduce the fontsize too

Comment: It is great! I have finished

Comment: Is it possible to make the arrow bigger? not the line, just the end of the arrow

Comment: See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-the-size-of-an-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf. Also this : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54796/how-to-set-default-style-for-arrow-tips-in-tikz is easier and may be solves your problem