# Changing the style of all arrow heads in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The `arrows.meta` tikz library allows you to change the style of an arrowhead. I think `-{Latex[length=2mm]}` looks nice for my figures.

However, I don't want to type "`-{Latex[length=2mm]}`" every time I draw an edge. How can I make this style the default for all arrows in the figure, so that I get this style of arrow head every time I write `->`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54796/how-to-set-default-style-for-arrow-tips-in-tikz/54797#54797

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you, that question didn't come up when I searched. I'll vote to close my question instead of deleting it, in case that makes yours easier to find.

Comment: For the sake of anyone with my exact question, the solution is `\tikzset{>={Latex[length=2mm]}}`. (after importing tikz and arrows.meta of course.)