How to remove axis border artefacts in pgfplots
My plot looks like this
as you can see there are some odd grey arrowheads (top right corner of each subplot) on the borders of the plots. I have no idea what is creating them or how to remove them.
Here's the pgfplots code for the first sub-plot
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
% Tikz stuff
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,calc,arrows.meta,fit,positioning,trees,backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    -Latex,auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,
    state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.5 cm, inner sep=2pt},
    point/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0.04cm,fill,node contents={}},
    bidirected/.style={Latex-Latex,dashed},
    el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left, sloped}
}


            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
                \begin{axis}[%
                    xlabel=,
                    ylabel=,
                    xmin=0, xmax=20,
                    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
                    width=\textwidth,
                    height=\textwidth,
                    samples=150,
                    domain=0:20,
                    yticklabel=\empty,
                    xticklabel=\empty,
                    ]
                \addplot[-, color=blue,thick,opacity=0.6] {0.5*sin(deg(2*x)) + 0.2*rand};
                \addplot[-, black,dashed] coordinates {(0,0)(20,0)};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

I am loading a bunch of tikz packages for this document too (included above), and perhaps they are interfering but I wouldn't have thought so.
Advice on this would be very welcome.

\tikset{-Latex,...} will add an arrow tip to almost any line you (and pgfplots) draw. Maybe you meant >=Latex? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54796/how-to-set-default-style-for-arrow-tips-in-tikz

Oh. Yeah that was it. Thanks!
